# How do I set the number of turtles in each patch using a .csv file full of data?

Tags: csv, import, patch, netlogo, turtle-graphics

Using some 35x12 matrix full of data in a .csv file, is there an easy way to import this into Netlogo and set the number of turtles equal to the elements of the matrix?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  We can help you more effectively if we can see what you've tried already, and you explain what's not working about it.

Comment: Well apart from brute force creating and asking the turtles to be in the required patches I haven't tried anything. I know this will work but it will take a while as there are 35 * 12  = 420 patches so before doing that I thought I would ask if there was an easier way! I already have the .csv file but I am new to netlogo

Comment: Have you checked http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html ?

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is :
first read the file into a list , then use location of each item and see if a patches pxcor AND pycor matches the location of the item in the list, then I set that number as plabel for double checking the number of created turtles:

```
extensions [csv]
globals [li]
to setup
  clear-all
  resize-world 0 34 0 11
  set-patch-size 30
  load-File
  ask patches [

    set plabel item (pycor) item (pxcor) li
    sprout item (pycor) item (pxcor) li
  ]


end
to load-File
  set li []
  file-open "t.csv"

  if file-at-end? [ stop file-close  ]  ;; protect against end of file
  while [not file-at-end? ]
  [
    let _line (csv:from-row file-read-line ",")
    set li lput _line li

  ]

end
```

[image]